# Limit width of HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to write a table so that it doesn't expand to the full width of the page. Below is what I have so far, but even though the first columns seem to respect the "width" parameter, the last column expands to the end of the page.

All results I found use CSS, but I am not sure how to do that. I don't know if it's relevant, but I'm writing a Joomla! article.

```
<table class="zebra" width="300">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align: left;" width="100">title 1</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" width="100">title 2</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;" width="100">title 3</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
      <td style="text-align: left;" width="100">content 1</td>
      <td style="text-align: center;" width="100">content 2</td>
     <td style="text-align: center;" width="100">content 3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I don't see it expanding http://jsfiddle.net/CVfje/

Comment: I am not experienced with HTML and CSS, but maybe I inherited something? This is a Joomla! article. It expanded on Firefox 15 for Linux.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
<table class="zebra" style="max-width:300px;">
```

Comment: If this was the solution, it would be interesting to know what the problem was. On popular browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE), the markup in the question does not demonstrate the problem described in prose.